# Resolving Excel VBA time millisecond inaccuracy

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using excel time format "hh:mm:ss.000" and adding 50ms at a time to cells in consecutive rows via VBA:

```
Dim dblTimestamp As Double
dblTimestamp = Selection.Value ' origin timestamp
' Setup base time increment of 50ms over 20 minutes

 For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
    Selection.Rows(i).Value2 = dblTimestamp + (2# / (864000# * 4#))
    dblTimestamp = dblTimestamp + (2# / (864000# * 4#))
 Next i
```

So you see the origin time below on 5/23/2015 and things start out fine:

```
5/23/2015 05:30:00.000
05:30:00.050
05:30:00.100
05:30:00.150
05:30:00.200
05:30:00.250
```

The problem is that the precision/rounding errors start to show up after a couple minutes (~1840 rows):

```
05:31:32.100
05:31:32.149
05:31:32.199
05:31:32.249
```

And then after 20 minutes it's more pronounced:

```
05:49:59.793
05:49:59.843
05:49:59.893
05:49:59.943
05:49:59.993
```

Can I use some other datatype for my calculations or do I have to brute force and add an extra millisecond every ~1840 rows?
I'd prefer a solution that would also apply when I change the time step to 200ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  Note that I removed your "selection" reference and am instead using "Now()" as the time stamp and placing values in cells A2 through A20000.  Functionally, you could combine all the time helper stuff into a single rounding function, but I designed it the way it is to feel more object oriented and to demonstrate a paradigm that's more adaptable. Hope this helps.

```
'A type used to store time data
Type TimeHelper
    MS As Double
    BaseTime As Double
End Type
'Value to use as millisecond
Const MilSec = 1 / 86400000
Sub Test()
    Dim t As Double
    t = Now()
    Dim step As Double
    step = 75
    Dim TH As TimeHelper

    For i = 2 To 200000
        t = t + step * MilSec
        TH = GetTimeHelper(t)
        t = RoundMS(TH, step)
        Cells(i, 1).Value2 = t
    Next i

End Sub
Function GetTimeHelper(t As Double) As TimeHelper
    x = t
    'Unrounded Hours
    x = (x - Round(x, 0)) * 24
    'Unrounded Minutes
    x = (x - Round(x, 0)) * 60
    'Seconds as Milliseconds
    GetTimeHelper.MS = (x - Round(x, 0)) * 60000
    'Time rounded down to nearest minute by removing millisecond value
    GetTimeHelper.BaseTime = t - (GetTimeHelper.MS * MilSec)
End Function
Function RoundMS(TH As TimeHelper, m As Double)
    'Construct a time from basetime and milliseconds
    'with milliseconds rounded to nearest multiple of m
    RoundMS = TH.BaseTime + (Round(TH.MS / m, 0) * m) * MilSec
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to round your date value after you have done the addition. Excel dates are stored as numbers under the hood and time is represented by a decimal. For example, 42249.6282730324 is 02/09/2015 (< to the left of the decimal) 15:04:43.550 (< to the right of the decimal) So you need to round this number. Here is a good post showing how you can do this using the INT, CEILING and MOD functions. http://exceluser.com/formulas/roundtime.htm.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just decided to check the text value after every row to see if it ended in a 9 and then add a millisecond if necessary:

```
Dim dblTimestamp As Double
dblTimestamp = Selection.Value ' origin timestamp
' Setup base time increment of 50ms over 20 minutes

 For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
    Selection.Rows(i).Value2 = dblTimestamp + (2# / (864000# * 4#))
    dblTimestamp = dblTimestamp + (2# / (864000# * 4#))

    ' check to see if previous value ended in 9 indicating loss of precision
    ' e.g. 05:30:00.999 instead of 05:30:01.000
    If Right(Selection.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text,1)="9") Then
      dblTimestamp = dblTimestamp + (1#/86400000#) ' add 1 ms
      Selection.Rows(i).Value2 = dblTimestamp
    End If
 Next i
```

This was good enough for my situation but P57's answer should still be good enough for other situations.